# Is their a way to export a MYSQL Table directly in java

Tags: java, mysql, database, export

Before anything, thanks you, english isn't my native language and i'm sorry for any mitsake i would make. If my question is stupid, i'm sorry too.

I'm making an application, that allow to export some tables in different format csv: no problem, xls: same, however SQL require more than putting some ",", Using PHPMyAdmin i noticed i can export the db directly in SQL, is their a way to directly get this sql code? I said in java as the app is in java, but ofc it might required something else and that's not an issue.

Anyways, thanks for going through my messy explanation, have a nice day.

Comment: Export to csv, spreadsheet are quite different from export to sql. In the first case, you're getting the data. In the second case, if you use something like mysqldump, you are getting the data *and* the metadata, such that the table/database can be recreated in such a way that it can be reused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use mysqldump command this can be used via Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

```
String command = "mysqldump -u username -p password database_name table_name";

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

$command = "mysqldump -u username -p password database_name table_name";

system($command);
```

or else u can go for mysqli approach

```
// Connect to the database
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database_name");

// Check for errors
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

// Get the data from the table
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table_name");

// Loop through the data and write it to a file or format it as desired
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Write the data to a file or format it as desired
}

// Close the connection
$mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run your .sql file with [ScriptRunner](https://ibatis.apache.org/docs/java/dev/com/ibatis/common/jdbc/ScriptRunner.html).

Here is the way you can use it.

```
Connection conn=getConnection();//some method to get a Connection
ScriptRunner runner=new ScriptRunner(conn, false, false);
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new 
FileInputStream("foo.sql"));
runner.runScript(reader);
reader.close();
conn.close();
```